# How to read file first line and write from the second

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file and I would like to read the first line and write from the second.

```
with open(file_path, 'r+') as f:
f.readline()
for values in my_array:
    f.write("%s=%s" % (str(values[0]), str(values[1])))
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: why don't you use _append_ mode? do you want to _insert_ a line at position 2, or just add a 2nd line to a file with only 1 line?

Comment: I'd like to rewrite the second line, replacing the text

Comment: then use provided answer. Don't play read/write on the input file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't write on a file while reading it.

Two solutions :

- Have a second file where you rewrite your first line and then write the second one :

  ```
  with open(file_path, 'r+') as f:
      line = f.readline()
  with open('another_file.txt', 'w') as outfile:
      outfile.write(line)
      outfile.write(...) # Whatever you want on your second line
  ```
- Store everything you want to write in memory and then write over your previous file (Which I don't recommend, if something happens midway and your file is stil overwritten, all previous data will be lost).